Associations and specializations in class diagram
In the following overview diagram I have not reported the fact that the type : tip attribute of Class3 is an enumeration that can take on two values ​​st or pt .
Is this diagram acceptable if I have to consider that spec1 can be associated with Class2 only if Class2 has an association with Class3 and type is pt?
This constraint must be implemented followed by any triggers right?


Yes, this is perfectly acceptable, because a diagram focuses on some elements of the choice of the modeler, and does not need to show all the models element and all the details. Here a quote in the UML 2.5.1 specifications, Annex A (highlighting by me):

A UML model consists of elements such as packages, classes, and associations. The corresponding UML diagrams are graphical representations of parts of the UML model. UML diagrams contain graphical elements (nodes connected by paths) that represent elements in the UML model.

Typically you would have Tip defined in some class diagram to document the acceptable literals.  The only problem of not having it directly in the diagram is if you refer to members in some formal OCL constraints to elements of that type and its literals.  But the problem is mainly human, i.e. for the reader to understand what the literals are.
About the triggers, I assume that you are considering a database implementation.  In that case you should indeed make sure that the relevant constraints are enforced, including in database triggers if needed. This does not necessary mean to implement the constraint as it is expressed,  but to take the necessary measures to make sure it stays valid (For example: The consistency enforcement can be quite tricky in this model, when deleting or changing a Class3 instance : it would require checking if it is indirectly associated with a spec1, and if it is, checking that all the relevant Class2 involved in this indirect associations as still associated with other Class3 instances that are of the good type)
P.S:  One would typically make sure that invariant constraints are enforced. For operations, it is sufficient to verify without necessarily programatically checking that no invariant is broken and the post-conditions are met.  Preconditions would typically be checked for defensive programming scenarios, or enforced at the level of the user interface, i.e. not even proposing operations for which the preconditions are not met).
